# What happened to my files?

Tags: upgrade, files, data-recovery, re-installation, users

After a successful upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 a gradual deterioration occurred -- my laptop became unstable with updates -- I corrected the Aspell file, only to have another appear, I sought but I was blocked out. Had an idea, but resolved one that another problem appeared -- going from bad to worse -- I re-installed windows Vista and Ubuntu 11.10 in the original partitions. Window called it **Windows Old** and I had no problems recovering my files there - Ubuntu decided it is going to make a new **Home** directory -- .
      the questions is where did these files go to after re-installation -- are they deleted? If so That's fine duplicates are in Ubuntu 1 by synchronization - I can only download one file at a time!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what happened based on your description, but there could be a few possibilities.  Ubuntu may have formatted your home partition and used it again, in which case the files would be deleted, but *might* be recoverable with some file recover tool.

Or it may have used a different partition as your home directory, in which case something else could be using that partition, or it could be unused.

Maybe try putting in a live CD and having a poke around all the partitions to look for the files you are after.

Good work on making a backup though!  At least you can restore them from the internet.

Comment: I had a hunch about the problem, but one thing leading to the other I intended simplify my life, and discarded Windows dormant in my laptop - Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Not many people could guess that, but you can always check wtih tools that are provided in ubuntu like Disk utility.

[image]

You can also help yourself with GParted.

[image]

The best way to reinstall is shown in this [article](http://www.muktware.com/man/2685). But basically you should always check the order of your partitions with Disk utility and then at install, select "Something else" to set the partitions by hand.

[image]

Good luck!